# Unable to pull username and password in SSRS connection properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, reporting-services, crystal-reports

I am migrating crystal reports to SSRS reports using a windows app, build based on .net code. Also I need to migrate the connection string with username and password. When I open the rdl post migration, I can see the connection string like shown in below image.

[image]

When I click on edit button, username/password is not populated automatically and I'm seeing those fields blank like shown below. I can notice the server name getting populated and not the user name and password.

[image]

Is there any property I'm missing the connection string or how can I auto populate user name and password without manual workarounds?

Really appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You may use shared data source instead of embedding the connection info in rdl file. If you have quite a few reports to convert, you may try crystal migration services to convert your reports automatically.